# What does an encoding speed of "[number] X" mean when using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, compression, encoding

When I run ffmpeg using

```
ffmpeg -i input.wav -c:a flac -compression_level 12 output.flac
```

I get 
[this](https://i.imgur.com/fjSDLty.png) result.

Meanwhile if I run it using

```
ffmpeg -i input.wav output.flac
```

which gives you the default compression level 5 I get
[this](https://i.imgur.com/UE5HLJF.png).

Obviously, higher compression takes way more time, but I don't understand what these numbers mean aside from giving me the ability to compare them to each other.

Answer (score 3):

It is the ratio of the duration of media generated with the actual processing time i.e. if 12 minutes of media has been generated after 3 minutes, then speed is 12m / 3m = 4x.